# Why Flask closing event loop in aiohttp.ClientSession?

Tags: flask, aiohttp, flask-admin

I',m using flask-admin with flask and trying to do GET response.

```py
@api_bp.route('/test/<region_id>', methods=['GET'])
async def test(region_id: str):
    api = current_app.config["API"]
    data = await api.shop.get_branches(region_id=region_id)
    return jsonify([i.json() for i in data]), 200
```

I'm trying to use the same session for requests, which will recreate itself if 30 minutes have passed. My goal is to use a session that has already accessed /login for external API requests, instead of having to access /login every time to get that authorized.

```py
    async def _request(self, url: str, request_type: typing.Literal["GET", "POST"]):
        session: aiohttp.ClientSession = await self._get_session()
        async with session.get(url, params=self._params) as response:
            return await response.json()
```

The first time I access /test/123, 5 requests are made using the session and I get a successful response.

But when I access it again, I get a closed event loop error.

I used the debugger to see what the problem was, and noticed that the event loop that is stored in the aiohttp.ClientSession object becomes closed. While the same code in another project (without Flask) works fine. It turns out that Flask itself closes it? But what for? What can I do with it?

I use aioflask for it.

I'm tried to use Quart, but it don't works with Flask-Admin.